# Hide/unhide table row given the row index and table ID

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I have this code to delete a table row:

```
var remove = document.getElementById(dataID); (this is the id of an object in the row I wish to hide)
    if(remove!=null){
        var v = remove.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById(tid).deleteRow(v); (tid is the table id, not the row id)
    }
```

However, instead of delete it, I'd just like to hide it. What's a good way to do this?

Also, in the future, I'm going to want to 'unhide' it at user request, so how can I check if it has been hidden? The if(remove!=null) is what checked if a row was already removed, so I'd need something similar.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById(tid).children[dataID].style.display = 'none';`

You may need `-1` on `dataID`

And `block` to show it again (or `inline` or whatever it originally was, for a `div` it's `block`).

JQuery:

`$('#'+tid+':nth-child('+dataID+')').hide();`

Comment: Sorry I don't believe I was clear enough in my question. 'tid' is not the ID of the row I wish to hide, it is the ID of the table. The information I have at hand is the table ID and the row index of the row I wish to hide.

Comment: I would have expected it to work but it's saying 'Cannot read property 'style' of undefined'. The issue does not appear to have anything to do with indexing by -1 for the rowIndex

Comment: Same result... can you think of a jQuery solution that might work?

Comment: @Hoser Weird. I tested it and worked fine. Check my JQuery version. `EDIT` I see now, the issue was I used wrong variable. Should have `been dataID`

Answer (score 2):

My own approach, in plain JavaScript:

```
function toggleRow(settings) {
    // if there's no settings, we can do nothing, so return false:
    if (!settings) {
        return false;
    }
    // otherwise, if we have an origin,
    // and that origin has a nodeType of 1 (so is an element-node):
    else if (settings.origin && settings.origin.nodeType) {
        // moving up through the ancestors of the origin, until
        // we find a 'tr' element-node:
        while (settings.origin.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'tr') {
            settings.origin = settings.origin.parentNode;
    }
        // if that tr element-node is hidden, we show it,
        // otherwise we hide it:
        settings.origin.style.display = settings.origin.style.display == 'none' ? 'table-row' : 'none';
    }
    // a simple test to see if we have an array, in the settings.arrayOf object,
    // and that we have a relevant table to act upon:
    else if ('join' in settings.arrayOf && settings.table) {
        // iterate through that array:
        for (var i = 0, len = settings.arrayOf.length; i < len; i++) {
            // toggle the rows, of the indices supplied:
            toggleRow({
                origin: table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[parseInt(settings.arrayOf[i], 10)]
            });
        }
    }
}

// you need an up-to-date browser (you could use 'document.getElementById()',
// but I'm also using 'addEventListener()', so it makes little difference:
var table = document.querySelector('#demo'),
    button = document.querySelector('#toggle');
// binding a click event-handler to the 'table' element-node:
table.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
// caching the e.target node:
var t = e.target;
    // making sure the element is a button, and has the class 'removeRow':
    if (t.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button' && t.classList.contains('removeRow')) {
        // calling the function, setting the 'origin' property of the object:
        toggleRow({
            origin: t
        });
    }
});

// binding click-handler to the button:
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // calling the function, setting the 'arrayOf' and 'table' properties:
    toggleRow({
        'arrayOf': document.querySelector('#input').value.split(/\s+/) || false,
            'table': table
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7tyen/3/).

References:

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).
- [`e.target.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/node.nodeType).
- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 1):

As you've asked for a jQuery solution...how about

```
var $remove = $('#' + dataID);

if ($remove) {
    $remove.closest('tr').closest().hide();
}
```

?

Comment: Please use [`closest('tr')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), rather than navigating through (potentially arbitrary) element ancestry.